# Why this Regex to determine a Valid Windows Folder File path is not working correctly

Tags: c#, regex

I have this Regex to Check for a valid Windows Disk path.

```
^[a-z]:\\?(?:[^\\/:*?""<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\\/:*?""<>|\r\n]*(?:[^./:*?""<>])$
```

Here I am giving this last part so that we do not allow Ending with Decimal and Special Characters
like it should not be like "d:\abc\def."

```
(?:[^./:*?""<>])
```

But now it is allowing a dot in the middle somewhere like

```
d:\sdsd.\
```

and not taking

```
d:
```

NOTE: I had picked this original Regex from somewhere on the internet.

```
@"^[a-z]:\\(?:[^\\/:*?""<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\\/:*?""<>|\r\n]*$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
   ^[a-z]:\\?(?:(?:[^\\/:*?""<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\\/:*?""<>|\r\n]*(?:[^.\\/:*?""<>])\\?)?$
A: ^^^^^^^^^^                                                                      ^
B:           ^^^                                                                 ^^
C:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
D:                                                                            ^^^
```

**A:** `^[a-z]:\\?` [...] `$` same as before
**B:** `(?:` [...] `)?` new group to make everything after the letter and colon optional (because I assume you meant you wanted `d:` to match)
**C:** `(?:[^\/:*?""<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\/:*?""<>|\r\n]*(?:[^.\\\/:*?""<>])` same as before except the backslash is added to the prohibited end character class, because we are going to specify that manually with:
**D:** `\\?` Ending backslash, optional - but if there is one, it can match only here, since it's included in the prohibited character class.

Comment: you have got it perfect. Works Excellent. But can you explain what is the |[\r\n]+ and |\r\n part for.

Comment: @BeeGees the '\r' and '\n' parts are escape characters for special characters that can't normally be typed. The \r codes for a carriage return, and the \n codes for a newline. The | is just a character that is not allowed in the filename, so it is included with all the others that are not allowed. The + after the brackets [] mean to match any amount of qualifying characters, and at least one.

Comment: Ok Got it. I am marking your answer as Accepted Answer. Thanx for your help once again.